# Checking for a file on remote computers via Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I have set up an MSI software installation to happen on startup, however, i have noticed certain machines for whatever reason are not installing the package. I followed Microsoft's setup on the MSI install so everything in theory should be fine.

What I want to do is check to see if a specific file is located on a machine or not. I have created a txt file with all of the machines IP addresses and i have tried a for each loop to run through the IP's in the text file and if it exists to output to a log file.

The problem I am running into however, is that all are returning as if the file does not exist and echoing out the else command into my log file. I know for a fact the majority of these IP's (computers) have the file in the directory I specified.

Edit:   now it gets stuck if that IP isn't there (I.E. the computer is turned off). Is there anyway to check for that?

```dos
ECHO ON
for /F %%a in (ips.txt) do (
    set host=%%a 
    if exist \\%host%\c$\ProgramData\dvsAnalytics\Encore\Config\Encore.ScreenRecording.ClientService.exe.config (
    rem file exists
    ECHO %%a>>"C:\some location\encore-install-success.log"
    ) else (
    rem file does not exist
    ECHO %%a>>"C:\some location\encore-install-fail.log"
    )

)
pause
```

Comment: Are you certain the user under which this batch file is running can access C$ on each of the hosts?

Comment: @EricJ. yes, I am running this bat file from my DC as the domain Admin.

Comment: @aschipfl Ok that seems to work, however, now it gets stuck if that IP isn't there (I.E. the computer is turned off). Is there anyway to check for that?

Comment: I have posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40143198) now. You should include the information of [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142654/checking-for-a-file-on-remote-computers-via-batch-file/40143198#comment67555520_40142654) into your question by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40142654/edit) it... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use an interim variable `host` to hold the value of `%%a`, simply use `%%a` directly:

```
for /F %%a in (ips.txt) do (
    if exist "\\%%a\c$\ProgramData\dvsAnalytics\Encore\Config\Encore.ScreenRecording.ClientService.exe.config" (
        rem ...rest of your code...
    )
)
```

---

If you insist on the interim variable, you need to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for it as it is set *and* read in the same block of code; otherwise, you will read the value present when the entire block is parsed. The changed code would look like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedexpansion
for /F %%a in (ips.txt) do (
    set "host=%%a" 
    if exist "\\!host!\c$\ProgramData\dvsAnalytics\Encore\Config\Encore.ScreenRecording.ClientService.exe.config" (
        rem ...rest of your code...
    )
)
endlocal
```

In addition, there is a trailing space after `set host=%%a` in the code in your question; if it is also present in your actual scipt, it becomes part of the variable value and will most likely disturb; to avoid that, the syntax `set "host=%%a"` should be used.

---

To check whether a host is available in advance you could use the [`ping`](http://ss64.com/nt/ping.html) command.

This works reliably for IPv4 addresses:

```
ECHO ON
for /F %%a in (ips.txt) do (
    ping -n 1 -4 %%a 2> nul | find "TTL=" > nul && (
        if exist "\\%%a\c$\ProgramData\dvsAnalytics\Encore\Config\Encore.ScreenRecording.ClientService.exe.config" (
            rem file exists
            ECHO %%a>>"C:\some location\encore-install-success.log"
        ) else (
            rem file does not exist
            ECHO %%a>>"C:\some location\encore-install-fail.log"
        )
    )
)
pause
```

And this is for IPv6 addresses:

```
ECHO ON
for /F %%a in (ips.txt) do (
    ping -n 1 -6 %%a > nul 2>&1 && (
        rem ...rest of your code...
    )
)
pause
```